# How to properly delete popup

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple popUp component that I use in my entire app, it get's called by emitting an event on click. There are two types of popUps, success and danger. The success popUp should disappear on it's own after 5 seconds, the danger should get closed when clicked on the x sign. Currently it works the way I have created it, but if the user creates more than one danger popUp, then a success one and again a danger one, the danger one disappears after 5 seconds and not the success one. How can I make so that my success popUp disappears properly after 5 seconds? I am calling it here like this but it seems that it does not delete them correctly:

```
if(obj.type === 'success') {
   setTimeout(this.closePopUp, 5000);
  }
```

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="popUp-wrapper">
    <div
      v-for="item in allItems"
      :key="item.id"
      :class="['popUp', `popUp--type--${item.newPopUpType}`]"
    >
      <div class="popUp-side">
        <p class="exclamation-mark">!</p>
      </div>
      <h5 class="popUp-message">{{item.message}}</h5>
      <div class="popUp-side">
        <p class="closing-x" @click="closePopUp(item)" v-if="item.newPopUpType 
        === 'danger'">X</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: () => ({
    allItems: []
  }),
  methods: {
    closePopUp(item) {
      const index = this.allItems.indexOf(item);
      this.allItems.splice(index, 1);
    },
    onPopUpCall(obj) {
      var newPopUp = {
        newPopUpType: obj.type,
        message: obj.message,
        id: obj.id
      };

      if(obj.type === 'success') {
        setTimeout(this.closePopUp, 5000);
      }
      this.allItems.push(newPopUp);
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.$root.$on('call-popUp', this.onPopUpCall);
  },
  destroyed() {
    this.$root.$off('call-popUp', this.onPopUpCall);
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`closePopUp` requires an item argument based on your code which you are not providing.

Try this:

```
if(obj.type === 'success') {
    setTimeout(() => this.closePopUp(newPopUp), 5000);
}
```